# How can I get the Declared Fields of a Java Class on an Annotation Processor?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

Hi I am currently trying my hand at an AnnotationProcessor for Java. The only problem I have now is how to get the Declared Fields for the class over which the annotation is placed.

Does anyone know how to get the fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the element, you loop over the enclosed elements and filter by element kind:

```
typeElement.getEnclosedElements().stream()
                .filter(e -> ElementKind.FIELD.equals(e.getKind()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Also able to use == instead of equals because kind is enum